# Select top ranked overlapping segment SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ranking

I am looking for a way to select the top ranked overlapping segments. Table would look something like this:

```
CODE   START                STOP                 RANK
shift  2016-07-20 05:00 AM  2016-07-20 08:00 AM  5 
late   2016-07-20 05:00 AM  2016-07-20 05:08 AM  1
break  2016-07-20 06:00 AM  2016-07-20 06:30 AM  2
```

This is what I would like my output to be:

```
CODE   START                STOP                 
late   2016-07-20 05:00 AM  2016-07-20 05:08 AM   
shift  2016-07-20 05:08 AM  2016-07-20 06:00 AM  
break  2016-07-20 06:00 AM  2016-07-20 06:30 AM
shift  2016-07-20 06:30 AM  2016-07-20 08:00 AM
```

So pretty much I would only like to see what the top ranked segment is saying about this person's state, but if they didn't have any state other than the standard "shift" segment then just show that they are on their shift.

Does it makes sense? Please shoot away any questions or proposed solutions. I can't seem to think of anything at this moment. I can select the top ranked segments, but not when they are overlapping.

**EDIT:** As you can see on my **desired** output the *shift* segment gets overridden by the *late* segment which has a higher rank (lower number means higher rank, as usual in ranking) from 05:00 AM to 05:08 AM, but from 05:08 AM since there is no segment overridding it, we go back to our default segment *shift* from 05:08 AM to 06:00 AM.

Then there is a scheduled *break* segment from 06:00 AM and 06:30 AM which again overrides the *shift*  segment. After this is finished we go back to our default segment *shift*  from 06:30 AM to 08:00 AM when the *shift*  ends.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay, a SQL puzzle, I can't resist! :D

Here's one possible solution. I don't have SQLServer at hand (using [my favorite database](http://www.snowflake.net) :)), but SQL should be mostly portable:

```
create or replace table ranges(
        code varchar,
        beg timestamp_ntz,
        end timestamp_ntz,
        rank integer);
insert into ranges values
        ('shift', '2016-07-20 05:00:00', '2016-07-20 08:00:00', 5),
        ('late',  '2016-07-20 05:00:00', '2016-07-20 05:00:08', 1),
        ('break', '2016-07-20 06:00:00', '2016-07-20 06:30:00', 2);

WITH PERIODS AS (
  select beg, lead(beg, 1) over (order by beg) AS end
  from (select beg from ranges union select end from ranges)
),
MATCHING_RANGES AS (
  select periods.beg, periods.end, ranges.code, ranges.rank
  from periods
  join ranges on (periods.beg >= ranges.beg and periods.end <= ranges.end)
  where periods.end is not null 
),
RANKED_RANGES AS ( 
  select beg, end, code, row_number() over (partition by beg order by rank) in_period_rank 
  from matching_ranges 
)
select code, beg, end from ranked_ranges
where in_period_rank = 1
order by beg;

-------+---------------------+---------------------+
 CODE  |         BEG         |         END         |
-------+---------------------+---------------------+
 late  | 2016-07-20 05:00:00 | 2016-07-20 05:00:08 |
 shift | 2016-07-20 05:00:08 | 2016-07-20 06:00:00 |
 break | 2016-07-20 06:00:00 | 2016-07-20 06:30:00 |
 shift | 2016-07-20 06:30:00 | 2016-07-20 08:00:00 |
-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Explanation (I use "ranges" for your original table, and "periods" for slices of these, like what you want in the output):

- In PERIODS we create all distinct moments in time, and use LAG to find the next one. Output is:

  ```
  ---------------------+---------------------+
           BEG         |         END         |
  ---------------------+---------------------+
   2016-07-20 05:00:00 | 2016-07-20 05:00:08 |
   2016-07-20 05:00:08 | 2016-07-20 06:00:00 |
   2016-07-20 06:00:00 | 2016-07-20 06:30:00 |
   2016-07-20 06:30:00 | 2016-07-20 08:00:00 |
   2016-07-20 08:00:00 | [NULL]              |
  ---------------------+---------------------+
  ```
- Then in MATCHING_RANGES, for every "period" we find all possible ranges from the defined table (also removing the last row, NULL), output:

  ```
  ---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
           BEG         |         END         | CODE  | RANK |
  ---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
   2016-07-20 05:00:00 | 2016-07-20 05:00:08 | shift | 5    |
   2016-07-20 05:00:00 | 2016-07-20 05:00:08 | late  | 1    |
   2016-07-20 05:00:08 | 2016-07-20 06:00:00 | shift | 5    |
   2016-07-20 06:00:00 | 2016-07-20 06:30:00 | shift | 5    |
   2016-07-20 06:00:00 | 2016-07-20 06:30:00 | break | 2    |
   2016-07-20 06:30:00 | 2016-07-20 08:00:00 | shift | 5    |
  ---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
  ```

  Note how that creates all combinations of ranges and periods that match
- Then in RANKED_RANGES for each row we compute its priority within its period:

  ```
  ---------------------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
           BEG         |         END         | CODE  | IN_PERIOD_RANK |
  ---------------------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
   2016-07-20 05:00:00 | 2016-07-20 05:00:08 | late  | 1              |
   2016-07-20 05:00:00 | 2016-07-20 05:00:08 | shift | 2              |
   2016-07-20 05:00:08 | 2016-07-20 06:00:00 | shift | 1              |
   2016-07-20 06:00:00 | 2016-07-20 06:30:00 | break | 1              |
   2016-07-20 06:00:00 | 2016-07-20 06:30:00 | shift | 2              |
   2016-07-20 06:30:00 | 2016-07-20 08:00:00 | shift | 1              |
  ---------------------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
  ```
- And then we simply select rows with rank 1 :)

Comment: Sounds freaking awesome... I haven't had a chance to test it in my environment but the solutions looks very plausible and very smart... Thank you for taking the time and having a go at it. I will test it and if everything works properly will sign your answer as good! :)